# adjective features - similar to beth Levin's verb classes?

Tags: english, nlp, adjectives

Beth Levin published research on verb classes/alternations - is there similar for the adjective category of words?
I can see references to countable/uncountable, gradable,absolute, of quantity/quality etc. - but no resource that seems to list the word form and the (potential) features.  Things like WordNet don't appear to cover this either - does anything?

Are there any morphological indicators, or am I looking at context/syntax based indicators if I am to try to manually identify features of an adjective?

Thank you for any information and assistance - big.j.

Comment: What system of syntactic rules are you correlating the potential adjective classes with? Levin's verb classes are determined by syntactic considerations; it happens to be the case -- and the book demonstrates it brilliantly -- that verbs of a feather (semantically) flock together (syntactically) as well. There are lots of feature systems one could use, but if you want useful categories, you hafta anchor them in syntax. Like Levin did.

Comment: Material you may find useful is William Frawley's 1992 _Linguistic Semantics_ (Lawrence Erlbaum). Chapters 3 (“Entities”, i.e, nouns), 4 (“Events”, i.e, verbs), and 10 (“Modification”, i.e, adjectives) are especially relevant.

Comment: I haven't read that yet, so I'll give it a go - thank you for the pointer.  And yes, I know I have to decide on the classes - but it also depends on what features others have already found (pre/post mod, physical/abstract, through to more specific etc.).  I would have thought there was more info and data - but it seems like nouns and verbs received all the attention.

Comment: Adjectives are just crippled verbs in English. In other languages, they're crippled nouns (Roman grammarians didn't even distinguish them from nouns -- they inflected the same, after all). And there are languages where adjectives are a closed class, with only a dozen or two. Verbs and nouns are where the action is.